# how do I open an image using the python image library?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I am using the image library with python for the first time and am trying to open an image on my pc. So I type in

```
Image.open(C:\Users\laurence\Google Drive\INB347 web 2.0)
```

and I keep getting this:

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax:` with the colon just after the C highlighted in red.

It does not mention this in the handbook which I am following. The example uses
a simpler file location: ('bride.jpg'). How do I open an image file please? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Image.open(r'C:\Users\laurence\Google Drive\INB347 web 2.0')
```

i.e., enclose your full path in quotes, and put `r` in front of it to denote is as a 'raw' string, meaning Python won't try to interpret it as anything other than what you put between quotes. You can read more about raw strings [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).